# RPM+Yum: install two packages with the same name and different versions simultaneously

Tags: installation, rpm, yum, simultaneous, slot

For moderators: this question is about **development** of RPM based installer.

I'm developing packaging system for our software. We've designed our update management so that when we want to move to the new major version, we change RPM package to install all files into another directory (with another suffix) and change the package version. We keep the same name for the package (like: a-package-1.0.0 --> a-package-2.0.0). We want to install the new package keeping the old one to make user able to continue work with the old version while he moving to the new one.

So there is no file conflicts between our packages and RPM utility install them simultaneously without any issues (rpm -ivh ...). But Yum thinks that the new version is an update for the old one.

Is there a way to produce such RPM packages to make 'yum install a-package-1.0.0 a-package-2.0.0' installing them both? Maybe some flag in the package have to be set? I've found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is no way to install two RPM packages with the same name and without file conflicts usnig Yum.

So in my case I need to use some version suffix included into the package name.

Comment: Correct, there is no way to do this. This is why you will see packages like `python` vs. `python3`, where the latter is the new version, but expected to be installed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I called RH and their preliminary answer is that there is no way to do this in YUM/RPM as this might cause confusion.  After some discussion among their engineers, there does appear to be a way to do this, but they said it is cumbersome.  I've asked them to send me their documentation (if any).  I'm afraid you will need to call their customer service line and make the same request.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the response from RH.

Thank you so much for your time on the phone today.  You called asking if there was a way of installing different versions of tools like maven or java using yum to install them.  After the engineers discussed it they have provided a document that shows you how to do this.  I must say, if you do not have a log in to the customer portal, you will not be able to view the whole document.

How to switch Java Environment in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and 6?
  - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21059

The engineers have also provided additional documents just for general use with Developer Toolset and Software Collections:

How to use Red Hat Software Collections (RHSCL) or Red Hat Developer Toolset (DTS)?
  - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/472793

Developer Toolset and Red Hat Software Collections use in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
  - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/915023

What's the difference between /etc/alternatives and the dynamic software collections framework?
  - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/528643

If you do require further assistance, please provide me with a valid account number, login, or contract number, and I can get a case started and you will be able to be in direct contact with one of our Red Hat engineers.